# Changing default folder detail-view options

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

When you view a folder in Detail view by selecting the menu option View > Details [Alt-V-D], the default details XP shows us are,

- Name
- Size
- Type
- Date Modified

I want to be able to have the `Date Created` also in the default options. How do I enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure a single folder to the settings you want (with the extra column), you can open the Tools menu and go to Folder Options. On the View tab, you should have the option to "Apply to All Folders". This will cause all folders to open by default in the same view as the current folder.

This may not be what you want, though, since it will cause all folders to open in Details view by default, rather than in Tile view.